# C/C++ string memory leaks?

Tags: c++, c, string, memory, memory-leaks

I'm using the STL `string` within an application of mine, and I was recently testing it for memory leaks, and I noticed that a lot of my strings weren't being properly deallocated by the end of the program.

I tested the following code (not verbatim) with one of the strings:

```
const string* cppString = &obj->objString;
const char* cString = cppString->c_str();
delete obj;
```

After that, I put a break-point and noticed that, while the `string` that `cppString` pointed to no longer existed, `cString` was still pointing to a C-style string, which surely enough, was the one that failed to be deallocated at the end.

Am I missing something in terms of how C/C++ strings work? How can I get the C representation of the string to be deallocated as well?

My `obj` class is of type `Dialog`, which inherits `Popup`. I thought that might've been it, since when I delete `obj`, I'm treating it as a `Popup*`, but I tried it in a small separate program, and deleting as a parent class properly removes the child member variables (which makes sense, of course).

I used the memory leak tracing within Visual Studio, and it shows that the string that ended up leaking was the one that was created when I made the `Dialog` and set the `objString` to the string passed as a reference to the constructor.

Comment: (Oops, my earlier comment suffered from a mistake in reading the operator precedence). I think you need to show more code. Without seeing the definition of `obj` and how its allocated, it's difficult to speculate whether `obj->objString` will be correctly freed.

Comment: It looks like a mess here, so I'm going to update the OP with my comment.

Comment: Does `Popup` have a virtual destructor?

Comment: @Adam: Brilliant! As I edited in my OP, I suspected that it wasn't making the proper destructor calls, but I likely did something wrong when I tried making the destructor virtual. I tried it now, and it works perfectly. I'll accept your response; would you mind mentioning that in your response so that it can help others that may have this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're seeing is **undefined behavior**—it's not actually a memory leak.  The memory for the C string *has* been deallocated (at least as far as you're concerned), but the data there is still technically accessible.  When you deallocate memory, the memory usually doesn't get erased, so the data there often stays around so long as the memory doesn't get reused by a subsequent allocation.

Reading data after it's been deallocated is undefined behavior: you might get what the data was before it was deallocated, you might get garbage data, you might crash your program, or you could even erase your hard drive (although that's not very likely).

So long as the `std::string` object is being properly deallocated, then any memory used for its C string representation will also be deallocated.  You don't need to worry about that.

---

**EDIT**: Actually it turns out your object wasn't getting fulled destroyed because the parent class `Popup` didn't have a virtual destructor.  As a result, the destructor for the subclass `Dialog` wasn't getting called, so the destructor for the `std::string` instance wasn't getting called.

Comment: That would make sense, but I used Visual Studio's memory leak detection procedure (which basically follows all of the `malloc` and `free` calls) and when I dumped the memory leak information at the end of the program, that string, among similarly positioned ones, shows up as not being properly deallocated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely not in `std::string`, but in `obj` (whatever type that is). Note that you deleted `obj`, not `cppString`. My guess is that `obj` does not store `objString` in a smart pointer class nor does it delete `objString` in its destructor, and hence you have that leak.

Comment: `objString` is a regular string, not a pointer, so it should automatically be deleted by the default destructor, no?

Comment: @Jengerer, you assigned from objString to type "const string*", not to type "const string", so it must be a pointer type, unless you've shared different code with us.

Comment: what I meant was that in the object class, `objString` is a `string` type and not a pointer. When I assigned it to the `const string*`, I did `&obj->objString`, so I used the & operator to get the address.