# What is the use of the c_str() function?

Tags: c++, c, string, c-str

I understand `c_str` converts a string, that may or may not be null-terminated, to a null-terminated string.

Is this true? Can you give some examples?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`c_str` returns a `const char*` that points to a null-terminated string (i.e., a C-style string). It is useful when you want to pass the "contents"¹ of an `std::string` to a function that expects to work with a C-style string.

For example, consider this code:

```
std::string string("Hello, World!");
std::size_t pos1 = string.find_first_of('w');

std::size_t pos2 = static_cast<std::size_t>(std::strchr(string.c_str(), 'w') - string.c_str());

if (pos1 == pos2) {
    std::printf("Both ways give the same result.\n");
}
```

**[See it in action](https://web.archive.org/web/20000000000000/http://www.ideone.com/XW4F0)**.

Notes:

¹ This is not entirely true because an `std::string` (unlike a C string) can contain the `\0` character. If it does, the code that receives the return value of `c_str()` will be fooled into thinking that the string is shorter than it really is, since it will interpret `\0` as the end of the string.

Comment: Very interesting point you made in Notes: what i would like to know if std::string is already contained \0 then c_str also append \0 at the end of string??

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: Yes, so you will have two null bytes -- one which is legitimately part of the string and one which is supposed to be the null terminator. But the c-style function that receives the pointer doesn't know this.

Comment: Note: a number of C-API will ask for two arguments (`char const*, size_t`), the second being the size, of course.

Comment: This is not working: `string str("0.85"); newVolume = _tstof((TCHAR*)str.c_str());` how can i convert TCHAR* argv[] input 0.85 into that?

Comment: @YumYumYum you cannot use `std::string` together with TCHAR stuff, the whole point of TCHAR is to automatically switch between char/wchar  while `std::string` works only in terms of char. You will have to use an appropriate abstraction, or just simply don't use TCHAR at all and always do a Unicode build.

Comment: One possible "appropriate abstraction" is `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`.   `std::string` is actually a pseudonym for `std::basic_string<char>`.

Comment: @Jon a stupid question, does using string with c_str cause any performance plenty? i.e if I want to make a desktop application if i used std::string with c_str will the performance be the same as using TCHAR/LPCSTR

Comment: Does c_str() create a copy of the original string?

Answer (score 71):

In C++, you define your strings as

`std::string MyString;`

instead of

`char MyString[20];`.

While writing C++ code, you encounter some C functions which require C string as parameter.
Like below:

`void IAmACFunction(int abc, float bcd, const char * cstring);`

Now there is a problem. You are working with C++ and you are using `std::string` string variables. But this C function is asking for a C string. How do you convert your `std::string` to a standard C string?

Like this:

```
std::string MyString;
// ...
MyString = "Hello world!";
// ...
IAmACFunction(5, 2.45f, MyString.c_str());
```

This is what `c_str()` is for.

Note that, for `std::wstring` strings, `c_str()` returns a `const w_char *`.

Answer (score 9):

Most *old* C++ and C functions, when dealing with strings, use `const char*`.

With [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) and `std::string`, `string.c_str()` is introduced to be able to convert from `std::string` to `const char*`.

That means that if you promise not to change the buffer, you'll be able to use read-only string contents.  PROMISE = **const** char*

Comment: @There's no such thing as `stl::string`. In fact, there isn't even such a thing as "STL" other than in a museum somewhere.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: STL is (was?) used as a synonym for the C++ standard library.

Comment: Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663186/initializing-a-two-dimensional-stdvector/59906780#59906780) from 2020. Or maybe it is due to [old books](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-criticise-Yashavant-Kanetkar-books-like-Let-Us-C-Why-dont-more-people-use-Turbo-C)?

Comment: Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083712/c-c-string-memory-leaks) (2010) - *"I'm using the STL `string`"*

Answer (score 8):

In C/C++ programming there are two types of strings: the C strings and the standard strings. With the `<string>` header, we can use the standard strings. On the other hand, the C strings are just an array of normal chars. So, in order to convert a standard string to a C string, we use the `c_str()` function.

For example

```
// A string to a C-style string conversion //

const char *cstr1 = str1.c_str();
cout<<"Operation: *cstr1 = str1.c_str()"<<endl;
cout<<"The C-style string c_str1 is: "<<cstr1<<endl;
cout<<"\nOperation: strlen(cstr1)"<<endl;
cout<<"The length of C-style string str1 = "<<strlen(cstr1)<<endl;
```

And the output will be,

```
Operation: *cstr1 = str1.c_str()
The C-style string c_str1 is: Testing the c_str

Operation: strlen(cstr1)
The length of C-style string str1 = 17
```

Answer (score 7):

c_str() converts a C++ string into a C-style string which is essentially a null terminated array of bytes. You use it when you want to pass a C++ string into a function that expects a C-style string (e.g., a lot of the [Win32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) API, [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) style functions, etc.).

Comment: I wouldn't say "converts". Rather, the function "provides access" to a suitable read-only character array -- most likely an array which has always been there in the implementation of `std::string` to begin with.

Answer (score 6):

It's used to make `std::string` interoperable with C code that requires a null terminated `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

You will use this when you encode/decode some string object you transfer between two programs.

Let’s say you use [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to encode some array in Python, and then you want to decode that into C++. Once you have the string you decode from Base64-decoded in C++. In order to get it back to an array of float, all you need to do here is:

```
float arr[1024];
memcpy(arr, ur_string.c_str(), sizeof(float) * 1024);
```

This is pretty common use, I suppose.

Comment: That kind of code is not portable (endianness and float format among other)