# Interpolating string from array with URL in C++ to perform GET request using libcurl

Tags: c++, get, libcurl, string-interpolation

I am trying to make a GET request for five different names using URLs that correspond to each name, but Xcode keeps telling me beside the line that says `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, namesURL);` that it `Cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'std::__1::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') through variadic function; call will abort at runtime`.

Is there a problem with my string interpolation that is causing this problem? I have tried to use `cout << typeid(stockURL).name() << endl;` to see what data types I am working with, but I don't understand the results I am getting.

```
    int main(){
        string names[5] = {"Joe", "Suzy", "Larry", "Sally", "John"};
        for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++){
          string namesURL = "http://names.com/" + names[i];
          cout << url << endl;


          CURL *curl;
          CURLcode res;

          curl = curl_easy_init();
          if(curl) {
              curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, namesURL);

              /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
              res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
              /* Check for errors */
              if(res != CURLE_OK)
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));

               /* always cleanup */
               curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try passing `namesURL.c_str()` instead. That gives you a regular `const char *` instead of an `std::string`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I will put that as the final answer.

Comment: Does the curl_easy_setopt expect a `const char`? Or is the string from the URL a `const char`?

Comment: `curl_easy_setopt` is a variadic function, the second argument determines how the third argument is interpreted. For example, `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` wants a number in seconds, while `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` wants 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Botje answered my question in the comments, pointing out that by passing `namesURL.c_str()` it is possible to get a regular `const char *` instead of a `std::string`.

For reference on the use of `c_str()`, check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416445/what-is-use-of-c-str-function-in-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).